# <a> link only functions if you click exact text. How do I make the entire <a> tag clickable?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, popup

My website has a modal-style popup window that appears when a user clicks this link:

`<li><a href="#contact"><label for="lightbox-demo">Contact</label></a></li>`

The problem is that this link only opens the popup **if** you click directly over the "Contact" text. If you click within the `<a>` tag, but miss the text, it won't do anything. How do I make it so if you click anywhere in the `<a>` tag, the popup opens?

The popup code (if needed) is:

```
<aside class="lightbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="state" id="lightbox-demo" />
  <article class="content">
    <a href="#" class="closest"><img src="img/x.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window"  alt="Close Contact Window" /></a>
 <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" required title="Whoops! Invalid email" aria-required="true"/>
       <div class="antispam">
       <br /><input name="url" type="hidden" /></div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Comment" required minlength="15" required title="Must be at least 15 characters"></textarea>
        <button id="flybutton">
            <p>Submit </p>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M4z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
</form>
  </article>
  <label class="backdrop" for="lightbox-demo"></label>
</aside>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the current markup that you have on the page you provided in the comments, then this CSS will allow you to expand the target area of the link.

```
<style>
   #nav > a{display: inline-block; padding: 10px;}
   #nav > a > li > label{cursor: pointer;}
</style>
```

The first rule using the padding to expand the clickable area of the link. The second rule changes the pointer for the text in the label from the default to the pointer so that it mimics the link. I would recommend restructuring your markup but if you leave it as is then hopefully this will fix your issue.

Comment: I assume you're referring to this markup?  --> <a href="#contact"><li><label for="lightbox-demo">Contact</label></li></a>  <--  If so, I've added your suggested code to the bottom of my CSS file, and reuploaded it here:  http://taskbasket.net/public/demo2.html   but the problem persists. Try for yourself.  The full css file is found here: http://taskbasket.net/public/css/main.css

Comment: I looked in the css link you provided and I don't see my styles anywhere. I made local copies of your page and added it and it worked for me. Are you sure you uploaded an updated version of your CSS?

Comment: Yeah, you may need to perform a hard refresh CTRL+F5 to view the changes. See the very bottom of : http://taskbasket.net/public/css/main.css. Then if you go to http://taskbasket.net/public/demo2.html and click just beneath the "Contact" text, you can see the pointer is enabled but it won't open the popup...

Comment: Any ideas why it's not working? I'd love to see your working files, this is driving me nuts

Comment: I was able to eventually solve it by placing a class "contactbox" to the label's associated with contact and login. This allowed me to play around with their padding and adjust it properly. Your answer lead me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code and you need to put `<a>` around `<div>` tag.

`<a href="#contact" class="loginbtn">
    <div class="logrow">
        <label for="lightbox-demo">Login</label>
    </div>
</a>`

However, I think it would be much better to use `<button>` tag just for Login button.

Your code should look something like this:

`<div class="logrow">
    <a href="#contact">
        <button class="loginbtn">Login</button>
    </a>
</div>`

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but it doesn't seem to work. Try for yourself here (click the LOGIN button on the far-right)  http://taskbasket.net/public/demo2.html  You'll notice that you have to click the exact Login text to work. The code for the Login button is:   <a href="#contact" class="loginbtn"><label for="lightbox-demo">Login</label></a>

Comment: Ivan, sorry to say but neither seems to work. Your first solution can be seen implemented here: http://taskbasket.net/public/demo2.html  and your second solution (with a button) doesn't address the *necessary* for="lightbox-demo" to open the modal, so now it doesn't open the modal at all!  . It can be seen implemented here: http://taskbasket.net/public/demo3.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be CSS, attempt to insert an attribute "display: inline-block" in the element "`<a>`".

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is where you are putting your anchor tag. Since it currently is wrapping around 'text' then that is exactly what the focus will be.

If you instead wrap the anchor around the list element, then you should be able to click on the list element itself. Let me know if the example below gets you closer to where you want to be:

```
<ul>    
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <li style="background-color: red;">
      Google!
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but isn't that what I'm doing here 
<a href="#contact"><li><label for="lightbox-demo">Contact</label></li></a> . You can view this code in action here: http://taskbasket.net/public/demo2.html